# Image change dependent of UISlider value

Tags: swift, image, animation, uislider

I have some images that need to be displayed dependent on the value of a slider. It is not working - where am I going wrong?

```
@IBOutlet weak var image1: UISlider! [this is connected to the slider NOT the image]

image1.setImage(UIImage(named:"image1.png"),forState:UIControlState.Selected)

@IBAction func sliderValue(sender: UIButton) {
    let slider value = Int(sender.value)
    if sliderValue == 1 {
        image1.setImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do something like that ? You check the value of your slider each time its value change, then you set an image to your imageView.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var sliderValue = Int(sender.value)
    if sliderValue == 1 {
        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "foo")
    }
}
```

To connect your Slider in your storyboard to your code :

1. In the right panel of your storyboard, select your ViewController, go to the third tab. In Custom Class > Class field, enter class you are using. It should autocomplete.

[image: First step]

2. Click on "SHOW THE ASSISTANT EDITOR" (two circles icon) to split your window between your storyboard and your code.

[image: 2nd step]

3. Press Ctrl + drag the element (here your slider) to the code.

[image: 3rd step]

4. Choose `Outlet` or `Action`. For your imageView, choose outlet, because you will be able to interact with it programmatically, but the user won't do any action with it. I'll let you search Google if you need more details on `IBOutlet` and `IBAction`

Credits : Images from [this site](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios/storyboards-outlets-actions/)

Comment: Thanks Olivier - I'm not sure how to connect it though - do I connect the outlet/action to the slider or to the image?

Comment: I found [this link](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios/storyboards-outlets-actions/), explaining how to do it with images, videos, and written explanation. I'll edit my answer to do a quick explanation of what you have to do.

Comment: It wasn't a case of not knowing how to connect them - it was a case of not knowing which outlets and actions to connect to which buttons to make the code work

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, but you can still find what you need in my answer, I put an example at the beginning of my answer. You connect your UIImageView with an IBOutlet, and your UISlider with an IBAction (event is called "value changed"). In the function created by your IBAction, you have the slider's value, and you can change the the image of your UIImageView